# Низкая скорость интернета Windows 10

Tags: windows, сеть, windows-10, tp-link

Подключил дома интернет, скорость скачки очень низкая ...допустим если смотреть фильм онлайн, то грузит быстро, то есть включил Play и смотришь, страницы открываются в лет, но через торенты скорость падает до 500 кб/с, большие файлы пробовал скачивать (Ubuntu 1.5 гб) не торрент соответственно, скорость все равно 500-600 кб, ноут подцеплен через wifi, так же к wifi подключен телефон, через play market пробовал скачать скорость 4-5 мб/с, что за хня такая может быть??
Я понимаю, некоторые провайдеры глушат торенты (хотя этот уверял, что не глушит) но обычный файл не торентовский с такой же скоростью качает...

Comment: Проверяйте скорость загрузки на сайтах с гарантированно хорошей пропускной способностью. Рекомендую Microsoft для HTTPS (обычно качаю какой-нить фреймворк в оффлайн-версии, это метров 80) и DLink для FTP (обычно качаю D-View, это около 200 метров). Также проверьте загрузку файлов в 2-3 потока - ограничение общее или на поток?

Comment: Ограничение идет общее, допустим если одновременно качать торент файл и обычный файл (через загрузчик браузера) то скорость у них одинаковая 500-600 кб/c...

Comment: То есть суммарно качается метр в секунду? тогда какое это в пень ОБЩЕЕ ограничение? это ограничение на поток. И вполне себе предмет претензий оператору. Но сперва убедись, что у тебя локально нет никакого сервиса (или настройки), вводящего это ограничения. *некоторые провайдеры глушат торенты* Это незаконно, противоречит требованиям закона о предоставлении телематических услуг, и при большом скандале может даже лишить излишне упыристого провайдера лицензии...

Comment: @Akina, как так быстро определили что провайдер виноват? Если говорить о `wi-fi`, то он изначально подвержен внешнему воздействию - забитый канал, удаленность от источника, плохой сигнал и тд и тп. Нет ни единого слова, что по кабелю ситуация точно такая же, а значит на основании проделанных тестов рано делать какие то выводы.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev 1) *если одновременно качать ... скорость у них одинаковая 500-600 кб/c* 2) *через play market пробовал скачать скорость 4-5 мб/с*

Comment: @Akina, и о чем это говорит? Я хорошо прочитал вопрос, не нужно мне выдергивать из контекста слова, которые не относятся к проблеме на ноутбуке.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Первая цитата говорит о том, что проблемы в канале - нет. Можно, конечно. представить, что сидит какая-то сволочь, и как только увидит параллельные закачки - включает скремблер, но я отношу это к разряду сказок. Вторая цитата говорит о том, что интегральная скорость закачки может быть поднята до значения на порядок больше. Вот если бы товарищ попробовал на телефоне загрузку не с play market, и увидел те же пять метров - тогда да, можно было бы точно утверждать, что проблема на ноуте.

Comment: @Akina, возможно вы угадали и с wi-fi проблем нет, но пока нет результатов тестов с ноутбука по кабелю - делать выводы рано и бессмысленно.

Comment: @Akina На телефоне я пробовал и не с плэй маркета, а с обычного сайта ubuntu.com качал от сюда дистр, скорость от 4 до 5.5 мб/с поднимается.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev по кабелю ноут не цеплял, сегодня патч корд сделаю и протестю, отпишу...

Comment: Т.е. телефон - быстро, ноут - медленно? Тогда @AndreyMihalev прав - проблема на ноуте.

Comment: @Akina да, но дело в том, что потоковое видео на ноуте (к примеру фильм в качестве 1080 hd идет без рывков, то есть нажал на плэй оно грузится хорошо (в онлайне)

Comment: *потоковое видео на ноуте (к примеру фильм в качестве 1080 hd идет без рывков, то есть нажал на плэй оно грузится хорошо (в онлайне)* Ну можно предположить, что процесс, тормозящий загрузку, тормозит только определённые порты/протоколы... autoruns в руки, смотрите, что грузится, procexp, смотрите, что работает, выгружайте-выключайте лишнее/подозрительное.

Comment: @Akina Ок, дома буду разбираться сегодня, сначала по кабелю проверю, потом буду уже дальше лезть..

Answer (score 0):

В общем ребят извиняйте за долгий ответ, был в командировке, вчера дома решил попробовать снова покачать торренты через своего чудо-провайдера. Скорость теперь норм что через WiFi , что через кабель (через кабель скорость выше), ну по крайней мере скорость теперь нормальная. В чем была проблема хз)

Comment: Таже фигня + в добавок обрывают постоянно, скажите спасибо закону про суверенный интернет